# How to run a coroutine and wait it result from a sync func when the loop is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a code like the foolowing:

```
def render():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def test():
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("hi")
        return 200

    if loop.is_running():
        result = asyncio.ensure_future(test())
    else:
        result = loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

When the `loop` is not running is quite easy, just use `loop.run_until_complete` and it return the coro result but if the loop is already running (my blocking code running in app which is already running the loop) I cannot use `loop.run_until_complete` since it will raise an exception; when I call `asyncio.ensure_future` the task gets scheduled and run, but I want to wait there for the result, does anybody knows how to do this? Docs are not very clear how to do this.

I tried passing a `concurrent.futures.Future` calling `set_result` inside the coro and then calling `Future.result()` on my blocking code, but it doesn't work, it blocks there and do not let anything else to run. ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use await out of a coroutine, it will result in a SyntaxError

Comment: Hi, I'm curious if my answer helped with the issue you were having?

Comment: Sorry did not comment before, yeah it helped somehow to realize I cannot do what I wanted jejej; I opted for creating an async api and on the sync rise an exception when people try to use async methods throw the sync api on async scripts/apps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To implement `runner` with the proposed design, you would need a way to single-step the event loop from a callback running inside it. Asyncio  [explicitly forbids](https://bugs.python.org/msg225883) recursive event loops, so this approach is a dead end.

Given that constraint, you have two options:

1. make `render()` itself a coroutine;
2. execute `render()` (and its callers) in a thread different than the thread that runs the asyncio event loop.

Assuming #1 is out of the question, you can implement the #2 variant of `render()` like this:

```
def render():
    loop = _event_loop  # can't call get_event_loop()

    async def test():
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("hi")
        return 200

    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(test(), loop)
    result = future.result()
```

Note that you cannot use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` in `render` because the event loop is not (and should not be) set for that thread. Instead, the code that spawns the runner thread must call `asyncio.get_event_loop()` and send it to the thread, or just leave it in a global variable or a shared structure.

Comment: This seems not to be working. Calling `render` blocks and never returns.

Comment: @AlQuemist How are you invoking `render`, do you have a runnable example?

Comment: Here is my snippet following your suggestion: https://pastebin.com/di8JFb21

Comment: The `reader` implementation applies to scenario #2, where you run the event loop in a separate thread, which your code is not doing. For example, [this works](https://pastebin.com/QCp1PA4z).

Comment: I posted a minimal example following your suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

**Waiting Synchronously for an Asynchronous Coroutine**

If an asyncio event loop is already running by calling `loop.run_forever`, it will *block* the executing thread until `loop.stop` is called [see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever)]. Therefore, the only way for a synchronous wait is to run the event loop on a dedicated thread, schedule the *asynchronous* function on the loop and wait for it *synchronously* from *another* thread.

For this I have composed my own minimal solution following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49333864) by user4815162342. I have also added the parts for cleaning up the loop when all work is finished [see [`loop.close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.close)].

The `main` function in the code below runs the event loop on a dedicated thread, schedules several tasks on the event loop, plus the task the result of which is to be awaited *synchronously*. The synchronous wait will block until the desired result is ready. Finally, the loop is closed and cleaned up gracefully along with its thread.

The dedicated thread and the functions `stop_loop`, `run_forever_safe`, and `await_sync` can be encapsulated in a module or a class.

For thread-safery considerations, see section “[Concurrency and Multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading)” in asyncio docs.

```
import asyncio
import threading
#----------------------------------------

def stop_loop(loop):
    ''' stops an event loop '''
    loop.stop()
    print (".: LOOP STOPPED:", loop.is_running())

def run_forever_safe(loop):
    ''' run a loop for ever and clean up after being stopped '''

    loop.run_forever()
    # NOTE: loop.run_forever returns after calling loop.stop

    #-- cancell all tasks and close the loop gracefully
    print(".: CLOSING LOOP...")
    # source: <https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2017-07-31-common-mistakes-using-python3-asyncio.html>

    loop_tasks_all = asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=loop)

    for task in loop_tasks_all: task.cancel()
    # NOTE: `cancel` does not guarantee that the Task will be cancelled

    for task in loop_tasks_all:
        if not (task.done() or task.cancelled()):
            try:
                # wait for task cancellations
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
            except asyncio.CancelledError: pass
    #END for
    print(".: ALL TASKS CANCELLED.")

    loop.close()
    print(".: LOOP CLOSED:", loop.is_closed())

def await_sync(task):
    ''' synchronously waits for a task '''
    while not task.done(): pass
    print(".: AWAITED TASK DONE")
    return task.result()
#----------------------------------------

async def asyncTask(loop, k):
    ''' asynchronous task '''
    print("--start async task %s" % k)
    await asyncio.sleep(3, loop=loop)
    print("--end async task %s." % k)
    key = "KEY#%s" % k
    return key

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop() # construct a new event loop

    #-- closures for running and stopping the event-loop
    run_loop_forever = lambda: run_forever_safe(loop)
    close_loop_safe = lambda: loop.call_soon_threadsafe(stop_loop, loop)

    #-- make dedicated thread for running the event loop
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop_forever)

    #-- add some tasks along with my particular task
    myTask = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(asyncTask(loop, 100200300), loop=loop)
    otherTasks = [asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(asyncTask(loop, i), loop=loop)
                  for i in range(1, 10)]

    #-- begin the thread to run the event-loop
    print(".: EVENT-LOOP THREAD START")
    thread.start()

    #-- _synchronously_ wait for the result of my task
    result = await_sync(myTask) # blocks until task is done
    print("* final result of my task:", result) 

    #... do lots of work ...
    print("*** ALL WORK DONE ***")
    #========================================

    # close the loop gracefully when everything is finished
    close_loop_safe()
    thread.join()
#----------------------------------------

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my case, my whole programe is async, but call some sync lib, then callback to my async func.

follow the answer by user4815162342.

```py
import asyncio

async def asyncTask(k):
    ''' asynchronous task '''
    print("--start async task %s" % k)
    # await asyncio.sleep(3, loop=loop)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("--end async task %s." % k)
    key = "KEY#%s" % k
    return key


def my_callback():
    print("here i want to call my async func!")
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(asyncTask(1), LOOP)
    return future.result()

def sync_third_lib(cb):
    print("here will call back to your code...")
    cb()

async def main():
    print("main start...")

    print("call sync third lib ...")
    await asyncio.to_thread(sync_third_lib, my_callback)
    # await loop.run_in_executor(None, func=sync_third_lib)
    print("another work...keep async...")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    print("done!")


LOOP = asyncio.get_event_loop()
LOOP.run_until_complete(main())
```