# Python asyncio: RuntimeError Non-thread-safe operation invoked on an event loop other than the current one

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, python-asyncio

I have setup a Python program that relies on `asyncio` and `socketio` to transfer messages between chat participants using two different chat systems (one interface being a CRM backend and the other being a javascript chat widget on a website).

The relevant part of the code is below. I need to open a separate thread for each independent chat. Therefore, in order to open a channel to the backend, I create a separate thread and run a "long_polling" function in it, which constantly checks for new messages from the backend via `pull_messages()` and sends them to the widget asynchronously via `socketio AsyncServer` (forwarding messages from widget to backend works fine and I leave it out here):

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=long_poll, args=())
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```

with the `long_poll()` function being defined as

```
self.server = AsyncServer(async_mode="sanic")

async def send_aio(self, msg):
    await self.server.emit(msg)

def long_poll(self):
    while chat:
        response = self.pull_messages(...)
        if response == "/end":
            chat = False

        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.send_aio(response))
        loop.close()
```

When the long_poll function is executed, just after the human response is fetched, I get the following error:

```
ERROR    asyncio  - Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<AsyncServer._emit_internal() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socketio/asyncio_server.py:344> exception=RuntimeError('Non-thread-safe operation invoked on an event loop other than the current one',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socketio/asyncio_server.py", line 354, in _emit_internal
    binary=None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socketio/asyncio_server.py", line 365, in _send_packet
    await self.eio.send(sid, encoded_packet, binary=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/asyncio_server.py", line 89, in send
    binary=binary))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/asyncio_socket.py", line 74, in send
    await self.queue.put(pkt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/queues.py", line 141, in put
    return self.put_nowait(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/queues.py", line 153, in put_nowait
    self._wakeup_next(self._getters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/queues.py", line 74, in _wakeup_next
    waiter.set_result(None)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1251, in uvloop.loop.Loop.call_soon
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 644, in uvloop.loop.Loop._check_thread
RuntimeError: Non-thread-safe operation invoked on an event loop other than the current one
```

Strange thing is, when I test locally via docker, this error does not happen, only once I migrate to Kubernetes (images and all other settings are the same).

What I have tried so far to analyze the situation:
Put `logger.info("Using thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))` into the `long_poll()` function, just before the error occurs. It tells me code is run in `Thread-n` (n is always 1 locally and usually some higher integer in the Kubernetes Pod), which is different from `MainThread` where other parts of my code with asyncio run, therefore I thought I am safe (I am aware the above asyncio code is not thread-safe). In case you have any suggestions, let me know.

---

*UPDATE:*

As user4815162342 suggested, instead of creating and destroying the event loops within the while loop, I created a single event loop in a dedicated thread and then pass the coroutine I need to run to the loop in the thread via `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`. Not sure whether I did everything correct here, but now this part of the code is blocking the rest of the program (e.g. no more messages from user to backend are possible...)

```
self.server = AsyncServer(async_mode="sanic")

async def send_aio(self, msg):
    await self.server.emit(msg)

def long_poll(self, loop):
    while chat:
        response = self.pull_messages(...)
        if response == "/end":
            chat = False

        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.send_io(response), loop)
        _ = future.result()

In the main program:
...
                loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                lpt = LongPollingObject()
                threading.Thread(target=lpt.long_poll, args=(loop,), daemon=True).start()
...
```

Comment: I don't think you can just create a new event loop at will like that, and have non-trivial asyncio code work. Some asyncio objects store the event loop instance and will break if you move them to another loop; some spawn background tasks (e.g. watchdogs or managers) in the event loop and expect them to continue running "in the background". Instead of creating a new loop every time, you should create a **single** event loop in a dedicated thread, and then use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` to submit tasks to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate further on how to achieve this? I understand I can create a dedicated thread using threading.Thread(...) and create a loop inside like I did above, but you're saying I should create it inside the thread and then submit tasks from outside the thread? Maybe silly question, but how can I reference the loop object created in the thread outside it `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`?

Comment: You can create the loop (but not run it) outside the thread, and pass it to the thread. The thread will do just `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop); loop.run_forever()`. Then you have your loop object to pass to `run_coroutine_threadsafe`.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried to do what you suggest, also based on another one of your [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330905/how-to-run-a-coroutine-and-wait-it-result-from-a-sync-func-when-the-loop-is-runn) where you seem to suggest the same and also provide some [code](https://pastebin.com/QCp1PA4z) which I tried to implement. But now it is blocking the rest of the program... please see the update above, maybe I have missed sth.

Comment: `set_event_loop` should be in the event loop thread, not before it. Another possible problem is that you are creating `AsyncServer` before creating your loop, so if it caches the then-current loop, the could be issues. To prevent that, you can take the existing event loop and move it to the other thread, i.e. use `get_event_loop` instead of `new_event_loop`. Finally, be sure to check the standard error and the logs for exception tracebacks.

Comment: hmm I think my whole approach of having everything inside the long_poll method was rather dumb, since this function was then actually preventing the rest from the main program to run.... Shouldn't I create the event loop and thread in the main program before I actually run the `long_poll()` method? I adjusted the update again, maybe you can have a look. Problem is now I get a `concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError` and the message from the backend never reaches the recipient

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by having a dedicated thread for the event loop. But the code makes even less sense now - the thread should be running `loop.run_forever()`, not `long_poll` - it is, after all, the point of the event loop thread to run the event loop. `long_poll` should run in the main thread (or wherever it needs to run in the logic of your program).

Comment: ok, but what I dont understand is that since there is this while loop in the `long_poll` function, which runs until the user on one side of the chat ends it, it will block the rest of the main code (which is responsible for forwarding messages of the other front-end), since it will not run in the background. Maybe could you modify and post the code here or on pastebin? I hope this would clarify much

Comment: It's supposed to work exactly like the code you originally posted, except the event loop runs in a dedicated thread. At this point I'm not sure how I can further help without you posting a minimal self-contained example that we can test.

Comment: I think I now see the confusion: you're supposed to have _two_ threads, one that runs `long_poll`, and one that runs the event loop. Your latest code simply lacks the thread that runs the event loop. I meant something like [this](https://pastebin.com/c2BXgD4B).

Comment: I tried the two thread variant as you outlined in the your code. Problem is the code fails at `_loop.run_forever()`, it says the loop is already running... Since in the logs it looked like everything in the right thread, I came back to your comment about the AsyncServer and its cached loop. What I did now is simply do the `get_event_loop()` before the `long_poll` thread is started and pass this loop via the `args` paramater of the Thread constructor to the long_poll function, where I use `run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.send_io, loop)`. This works, which works.

Comment: Using `threading.enumerate()` to track threads, I can see that for every chat a "long poll thread" is created and the rest (including the `AsyncServer.emit()`) is run in MainThread.